# Concatenate 2 RawQuerySets Django

Tags: python, django, rawsql

so i have tables with same purpose for each entity and they are from legacy system, thats why i cannot perform migration. For example :

- Entity1 Blog
- Entity1 Entry
- Entity2 Blog
- Entity2 Entry
  **There are 9 entities, means 18 tables**

So here is my view.py but i cannot do entity1_data.union(entity2_data). How can i merge these, so i can present it in 1 table?

Ps: i would try union SQL, but theres too long.

```
    entity1_data = BlogModel.objects.using("bcdb").raw("SELECT blog.id as id, blog.name," +
    "entry.title, " +
    "entry.date " +
    "FROM [Entity1 Blog] as blog  " +
    "INNER JOIN [Entity1 Entry] as entry  " +
    "on blog.id = entry.blog_id")

    entity2_data = BlogModel.objects.using("bcdb").raw("SELECT blog.id as id, blog.name," +
    "entry.title, " +
    "entry.date " +
    "FROM [Entity2 Blog] as blog  " +
    "INNER JOIN [Entity2 Entry] as entry  " +
    "on blog.id = entry.blog_id")
```

I hope i can do it dynamically using dict of tables name.

```
Merged table
| Blog ID            | Blog Name            | Entry Title            | Entry Date            |
| ------------------ | -------------------- | ---------------------- | --------------------- | 
| [Entity 1 Blog].ID | [Entity 1 Blog].name | [Entity 1 Entry].title | [Entity 1 Entry].date |  
| [Entity 2 Blog].ID | [Entity 2 Blog].name | [Entity 2 Entry].title | [Entity 2 Entry].date | 
| [Entity 9 Blog].ID | [Entity 9 Blog].name | [Entity 9 Entry].title | [Entity 9 Entry].date |
```

Comment: Are you getting some error or something? Why you can't do a union?

Comment: do you mean Django Union or SQL Union?